# fscanf C makes "program stopped working"

Tags: c, scanf, codeblocks

I'm learning about `fprintf` and `fscanf`. I wrote simple program:

```
int main()
{
  char t[20];
  FILE *fp;
  fp=fopen("a.txt","w");
  fprintf(fp,"test");
  fscanf(fp,"%s", t);
  printf("%s", t);
  fclose(fp);
  return 0;
}
```

`fscanf` makes error, which show window with "program stopped working". File was created proberly and it has "test" text inside.

I dont know whats wrong with it. Im using Codeblocks

Comment: You forgot to test if `fopen` returnn `NULL` which means that the file could not be opened, so any further attempt to read from `fp` will result in _undefined behaviour_ (google that). And furthermore the file is opened in write mode so trying to read from it is also UB. And even if everything was OK you still need to rewindthe file before reading from it.

Comment: I know about it, but there is same result with it

Comment: What was the data you were trying to read with an unrestricted `fscanf` into a buffer of length 20?

Comment: You're **reading** from a file that was opened **for writing and writing only**. `fscanf` **fails** and returns `EOF`, and sets `errno`; neither of which you never check.

Comment: the posted code does not compile!  It is missing the needed statement: `#include <stdio.h>`  for functions: `fopen()`, `fclose()`, `fprintf()`, `fscanf()`, `FILE`

Comment: when calling system functions: `fopen()`, `fscanf()`, `fprintf()`: always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: when calling `fscanf()`, the use of the input format specifier '%s' can overrun the input input buffer.   Always include a MAX CHARACTERS modifier that iis one less than the length of the input buffer because '%s' always appends a NUL byte to the input.   Suggest: `fscanf(fp,"%19s", t);`

Comment: the posted code contains 'magic' numbers. 'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis.  I.E. 20.  'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  Suggest using a `enum` statement or `#define` statement to give that 'magic' number a meaningful name, then using that meaningful name throughout the code

Comment: note even 'simple' programs need appropriate error checking and understanding of the system functions being used.  Suggest: read the MAN pages for each of the system functions being used

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) consistently indent the code. Indent after every opening brace '{'. unindent before every closing brace '}. Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces.

Comment: Did my answer solve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

#### Problems

- You are reading the file without reading permission
- At the end of the writing the file. Pointer is at the end of the file

#### Solution

- Open the file with read and write permission using `w+`
- rewind the file pointer to the beginning of the file using `rewind(fp)`

#### Code

```
int main()
{
    char t[20];
    FILE *fp;
    fp=fopen("a.txt","w+");
    fprintf(fp,"test");
    rewind(fp);
    fscanf(fp,"%s", t);
    printf("%s", t);
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Note:

- You should check whether the file has been opened successfully or not.

  ```
  if(fp=fopen("a.txt","w+"))
  {
     . . . 
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You want this:

```
int main() {  
    char t[20];
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("a.txt", "w+");   // open in read/write mode
    fprintf(fp, "test");
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);      // rewind file pointer to the beginning of file
    fscanf(fp, "%s", t);
    printf("%s", t);
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
  }
```

The program is still bad, because:

1. there is no error checking for `fopen`
2. the buffer might overflow, `fscanf(fp, "%19s", t)` would be more appropriate

Answer (score 0):

You have opened the file in write mode.The problem occurs when you try to read from it with the fscanf function. After you write to the file, close it and reopen it in read mode.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
     char t[20];
     FILE *fp;
     fp=fopen("a.txt","w");
     fprintf(fp,"test");
     fclose(fp);
     fp=fopen("a.txt","r");
     fscanf(fp,"%s", t);
     printf("%s", t);
     fclose(fp);
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: readability by humans is highly important.  The posted code has random indenting  That random indenting makes the code very difficult to read/understand.  Suggest using 4 spaces for each indent level and never using tabs for indenting.